# Build & Deploy on Save

Tags: java, windows, maven, tomcat, notepad++

Is it possible to auto-build and auto-deploy on save of a file in a web application using any editor? If so, how would it be done?

I already have a maven build script but it's manual each time I make a change I have to run `mvn clean install -P` and `mvn tomcat6:redeploy`. I'm not sure how to make this line run on save event. I haven't tried anything that would trigger my script's execution on save because I'm not sure how.

Comment: You're trying to make a simple editor behave (in one respect) like a full-fledged IDE. Is there any reason why you don't want to simply *use* an IDE of your liking?

Comment: A lot of front-end developers like to use Notepad++ or Sublime without having to know much about Java, IDE's and application servers.

Comment: Automatically compiling/deploying/installing things on save **is** the major feature that an IDE provides. You *do* in fact like to use an IDE, you're just not yet aware of it.

Comment: In notepad++, isn't there an option somewhere in the preferences to run a command line on save?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I played around with some plugins and found **NppExec** which allows me to save and run a command when pressing ctrl F6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write an application to monitor all the folders and files in development and then trigger your build when anything is updated or added. I think .NET comes with a control to do this.

Some editors may have the ability for add-ins as do many IDE.

I think you lose control by making things too automated. I prefer a short-cut.

Comment: I'm guessing that he's referring to deployment to an app-server that he's using for debugging. If somehow, his environment mandates a rebuild on every small change, that would definitely get annoying.

Comment: @Katana314 - good point. I was in the process of changing that as you posted.